# Reference a Subform in a Subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a report that has a Subreport. The Subreport references an ID that will populate the subreport.  I keep getting an `Enter Parameter Value` error.  If I put in the correct ID in the box and click ok the report populates correctly.  So my assumption is that I have not referenced the ID correctly, but I can not figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

The report will work in the form until I insert it in to another form.  I have a Navigation form called `Main`, a subform named `ProductsList`, and a subform inside of `ProductsList` called `SupplierDS`.  The control name is `ID`.  This is the reference I have:

```
[ID]=Forms![Main]![ProductsList].Form![SupplierDS].Form![ID]
```

Is this the correct reference to access the control ID?

This is the VBA code that I am using to reference the ID:

Private Sub Command524_Click()

Dim stDocName As String

stDocName = "SupplierDS"

DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , "[ID]=Forms![Main]![ProductsList].Form![SupplierDS].Form![ID]"

End Sub

Comment: Where exactly did you place that code? It seems correct, but it's not clear to me what you're doing with it.

Comment: I have placed a print button on the SupplierDS Sheet.  This is part of a Do.Cmd in VBA.

Comment: Then share that. You can likely fix this by modifying that statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string concatenation to make the statement work independent of where the form is:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview, , "[ID] = " & Me!ID
```